# Random discrete shape

Tags: python, matrix, random

I'm trying to generate (in python) a random closed shape. Think, a sort of random blob within some nxn grid.

That is, given an nxn grid, I want to be able to generate a random blob; for n large, it should have the appearance of smoothness on the boundary.

Preferably, the blob fills the majority of the specified nxn grid.

Does anyone know a good way to do this/ a suggestion starting source? I've thought about some hack-ey version of a random walk that is forced to return to its origin point within some time range, but this seems possibly rather difficult.

I also thought about (for the larger n*m x n*m) grid, using some discretized version of Voronoi polygons, but I'm not totally sure how to discretize the Voronoi-type algorithm.

Thoughts?

Comment: that's a good question. How will you create the boundaries of you your blob? if you know that part, then you can have look at flood-fill algorithms https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2011/08/11/recursion-explained-with-the-flood-fill-algorithm-and-zombies-and-cats/

Comment: @Ereli Yes the boundary part is the issue. I was planning on using a modified flood-fill once i figure out how to draw the boundary. (modified being i want a certain gradient fill)

Comment: I think you need to randomly generate some points and create a Convext Hull https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html

Comment: @Ereli Not a bad idea -- but why should a random blob be convex?

Comment: What do you mean by "random closed shape"? A non-intersecting polygon that is chosen with uniform probability from the space of all such polygons with vertices constrained to lie on the grid? Or -- do you mean something else? Your smoothness criterion and statement that "preferably, the blob fills the majority of specified nxn grid" suggests that you might *not* want something chosen with uniform probability. Clarifying just what it is that you want is a good place to start.